# Шаблонизация страниц React с передачей методов родителей

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть сайт со страницами входа, регистрации и восстановления пароля. Каждая страница это отдельный html файл и все эти страницы выглядят одинаково (за исключением самих форм).

Чтобы не писать одно и тоже был создан компонент шаблон. Тут все стандартно - шапка, тело с контентом и подвал:

```
class Pattern extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {}

        this.handlers = { //хэндлеры компонента, необходимые на каждой странице
            log: (message) {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header />

                <Container>
                    {this.props.children} //все формы и контент будут рендериться здесь
                </Container>

                <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Конкретно здесь `this.props.children` это компонент Form:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Card">
                <form>
                    {this.props.children} //тут различные инпуты и кнопки
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

И все это собирается воедино так:

```
class Sign extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <Pattern>
            <Form>
                <input type="text" />
                <button onClick={this.handlers.log.bind("hello, world!")}>LOG</button>
                <button onClick={() => console.log(this.isLoading)}>IS LOADING</button>
            </Form>
        </Pattern>
    }
}
```

Ключевые строки тут это вызовы `this.handlers.log` и `console.log(this.isLoading)`. `this.handlers.log` была объявлена в компоненте `Pattern`, а `isLoading` это состояние компонента `Form`. Так вот, создавая шаблон страницы (`Pattern`) я хочу, чтобы все дочерние элементы каким-то образом имели доступ к состояниям и методам всех родительских компонентов, при этом не создавая лишних функций и состояний в самом компоненте `Sign` и не используя роутер.

Подскажите, многого ли я хочу, как можно поступить в моем случае и если все не правильно, то что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы хотите обработать события в родительских компонентах. Это можно сделать так:
es6:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: false };
  }
  // У стрелочной ф-ции контекст всегда привязан к объекту экземпляру 
  // Parent подробнее https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6Cv--A7m5k&t=1s
  handleClickSave = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    ...
    // После установки isLoading дочерние компоненты перерисуются
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    
    saveDataRequest()
      .finally(() => { 
        // убираем загрузку при любом исходе запроса
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
      })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <FormComponent
        isLoading={this.stae.isLoading}
        onClickSave={this.handleClickSave}
      />
    )
  }
}


// FormComponent
import React from 'react';

const Form = ({ isLoading, onClickSave }) => (
  <form>
    ...
    <button
     disabled={isLoading}
     onClick={onClickSave}
    >
      Save 
    </button>
  </form>
)
```

пс не пишите `onClick={this.handlers.log.bind("hello, world!")}` в таком виде после каждого рендера создается по функции. Так как bind возвращает функцию.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. В целом мысль ясна и понятна. С bind запомню ;)